# Cannot search in NSMutableArray using threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I have 2 lacs of data in an `NSArray`. I have to search in that `NSArray`. Presently I'm splitting this `NSArray` and searching them in separate threads else it would take long time. I'm able to search the datas but cannot combine it to another `NSArray`.

For example, if I search for "a" I get all results with "a" in all the threads. But these threads result cannot be combined to a single `NSArray`.

The code I used is as follows

```
NSArray *subArray = [mArrayOrginalData subarrayWithRange:range]; 
                SearchOperation *anOperation = [[SearchOperation alloc]init];
                [anOperation setSearchData:[subArray mutableCopy]];
                [anOperation setPattern:txtFieldPattern.text];
                [anOperation setTarget:self];
                [anOperation setAction:@selector(searchResultHandler:)];
                [searchQueue addOperation:anOperation];
```

The code for retrieving data is another class(NSOperation) the code is as given below

```
@implementation SearchOperation

- (void) main{
    
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    
    NSMutableArray* mArrayTmp = [Search searchByPattern:self.pattern inputArray:searchData];
    NSLog(@"Sub result count : %d",[mArrayTmp count]);
    [target performSelector:action withObject:mArrayTmp];
}

@@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good from what I can tell.
Your observing target would have something like this...

```
- (void) searcherDidFindMatch: (id) match {
    [self lazyInitMatchesArray]; // init your NSMutableArray lazily here
    @synchronized(_matchesArray) {
        [_matchesArray addObject: match];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the search logic is processing intensive enough (even against a single element of your NSArray) to warrant having many threads.

The solution you describe will work but in your target you'll need to have a synchronized NSMutableArray for receiving the matching records.  Synchronizing may bottleneck things depending on the rate of matching.

In case you are not doing so yet, please run these NSOperations via an NSOperationQueue so as to benefit from GCD.

Comment: I am using NSOperationQueue. Could you pls explain Jason how to implement it actually i'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds dubious that you have a search function where splitting the array into sub-arrays and searching in threads is a performance win.   Sounds like there may be a need for a revisit to your data model.

But, OK, it can happen.   In that case, I'd split the array into N parts and enqueue the search-each-N into a concurrent queue, using a semaphore or like to limit the # of simultaneous searches occurring.   I would collect the results into N arrays and then, if necessary, summate them into a single array using `NSMutableArray`'s `addObjectsFromArray:` (which is pretty darned fast).